# How do applications remember authentication for sometime?

Tags: linux, authentication, passwords

In linux, some of the applications are able to remember authentication for a while. For example,

- File manager remember authentication for a while, when we provide password to mount a partition. If we mount another partition soon after mounting first one, it won't ask for a password.
- Terminal applications, if we execute some task with `sudo` and provide password, it won't ask for next `sudo` action if it is performed within a time period.

How this functionality is implemented? How can I make my application to remember root authentication for sometime?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled by the `sudo` program and its graphical variants (e.g. gksudo for Gnome). If you have an application that needs root privileges, running it through `sudo` will provide the authentication and remember it for a certain length of time, usually five minutes.